# NextJS - Unexpected Token Import

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js

While integrating react-syntax-highlighter into my next-js project I've used the following code:

```
import { Prism as SyntaxHighlighter } from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { okaidia } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";

...

<SyntaxHighlighter language="jsx" style={okaidia}>
{some code goes here}
</SyntaxHighlighter>

...
```

I get the following error upon running npm run dev, but only if I run the page directly.

```
Unexpected token export
/Users/johndetlefs/repos/tal-gel-framework/node_modules/react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export { default as coy } from './coy';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism (/Users/johndetlefs/repos/tal-gel-framework/.next/server/static/development/pages/components.js:7242:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/johndetlefs/repos/tal-gel-framework/.next/server/static/development/pages/components.js:23:31)
    at Module../pages/components.js (/Users/johndetlefs/repos/tal-gel-framework/.next/server/static/development/pages/components.js:6839:104)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/johndetlefs/repos/tal-gel-framework/.next/server/static/development/pages/components.js:23:31)
    at Object.3 (/Users/johndetlefs/repos/tal-gel-framework/.next/server/static/development/pages/components.js:7175:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/johndetlefs/repos/tal-gel-framework/.next/server/static/development/pages/components.js:23:31)
    at module.exports../js/config/libs/_theme-foundation--colors.js.config.themes.list.name (/Users/johndetlefs/repos/tal-gel-framework/.next/server/static/development/pages/components.js:91:18)
```

If I navigate to the page via  another page then everything works great. If I then refresh the page I get the error.

Removing the line

```
import { okaidia } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";
```

and removing the style attribute from the component fixes everything, but uses the default prism style, which is not the desired outcome.

Looking around I can see people have *similar* issues, and that the fix probably has something to do with the next.js.config file, and how the css file is being loaded server-side, but I'm not 100% what to do there.

Assuming the next.js.config file is a part of the solution, here are the current contents.

```
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");

module.exports = withCSS(
  withSass({
    webpack(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: {
            limit: 100000
          }
        }
      });
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
      });
      return config;
    }
  })
);
```

I've tried both with & without withCSS and the issue stays the same.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After digging around for a while, I checked out the npm packages directory and found that there are two types of dists: `cjs & esm`. The simple fix is just using the `cjs dist` instead of the `esm dist`.

`import { darcula } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/cjs/styles/prism';`

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry @Rotinx, I didn't mean to downvote, but it says that my downvote is locked until the post is edited, so I'm gonna delete the downvote and upvote it as soon as it's edited.

Comment: Haha no problem I appreciate your honesty, I've approved your edit.

Comment: Thank you ! Worked perfectly :D

Comment: This fixed it for me!